# Test suite issue in robotium

Tags: android, junit, robotium

I have one test case file with around 20 methods (test cases) which extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2. I need to write a suite which will call only selected test case methods, I know in junit there is one method which accepts the methods to be executed

```
    suite.addTest( new AllTestCases("testcase1"));
```

Is there a similar way to do stuff in android robotium? If yes, please help me out with a way to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a call like `new AllTestCases("testcase1");` because all Android related test classes inherit from either `AndroidTestCase` or `InstrumentationTestCase` and neither of these classes expose a constructor that takes a string as an argument.

You could take a look at `android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder` but even this class does not allow for the running of individual test methods, it accepts tests at the package level.

You might have some luck achieving your goal by using the Android test annotations such as `@SmallTest`, `@MediumTest`, `@LargeTest` etc. These will allow you to target only the specified annotated methods using the follwing command:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e size <small|medium|large> com.youproject.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

Finally, its possible to target individual tests methods or classes directly from within eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

To run an individual test case directly from command line:

`adb shell am instrument -w -e class` <***Test-Class-With-Package-Name***>`#`<***Test-Method-Name***> <***Package-Name-Of-Test-App***>`/`<***Instrumentation-Name-Defined-In-Manifest***>

**Example:**

`adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.myapp.test.ActivityFragmentTest#testLogin com.myapp.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`

Answer (score 0):

You can run individual test cases programmatically with "-e" arguments to the "adb shell am instrument" command. For example, for a method 'testFoo()' in 'com.foo.bar.FooTest' you could run:

adb shell am instrument -w \
 -e "class com.foo.bar.FooTest#testFoo" \
 com.foo.bar.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/testing_otheride.html